# Simple Sound Button App Error

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make a simple sound button app that plays a ringtone when the button is pressed. The problem I'm having is it works when I play an mp3 file but it keeps returning "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" when trying to play an m4r.

Here's my code so far:

```
let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "justdoit", ofType: "m4r")

var player = AVAudioPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        do {

            try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!))


        } catch {

            print("No audio path")

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please replace the code and let me know if you are getting no file path error.
let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "justdoit", ofType: "m4r")
var player = AVAudioPlayer()
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
        do {

           if audioPath != nil
{
            try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!))
}else
{
  print("Error there is not file at this path")
}
        } catch {

            print("No audio path")
        }
    }

Comment: @ManishPathak yea its printing out Error There is not file at this path

Comment: Can u make sure that file is actually there or not

Comment: @ManishPathak yea i've tried deleting the file and dragging it back into the folder

Comment: When you add a file by dragging just make sure you select target properly in the pop up window.